# How to retrieve data that is already on a webform using using C#

Tags: c#, webforms, webrequest

I am working on a program that accesses router pages and retrieves data (specifically wifi security codes)  It's not a hacking tool as it only works if your computer is already connected to it successfully.  The problem is that when I want to READ data that's already on the page (in like text boxes) I have to use regular expressions as the router always returns the html source instead of an say an xml data sheet (even when i set ContentType to text/xml).

Is there a way to similarly to my code that writes data to webforms that reads the data from webforms.  Here's my code example that writes to the "password" field and submits it to the router.

```
string formParams = string.Format("password={0}", loginInput);
WebRequest loginPage = WebRequest.Create(url);
loginPage.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
loginPage.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
loginPage.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream os = loginPage.GetRequestStream())
{
   os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Heres an excerpt of the html code from the webpage where that code writes the data that's in loginInput.

```
   <td class="form_label">Password&nbsp;:</td>
<td class="form_data">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" tabindex="100" />
</td>
```

Comment: You should look at using the HTML Agility Pack to parse/read the page using XPATH expressions.  http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

For example, here is how you would fix all hrefs in an HTML file:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
{
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
}
doc.Save("file.htm");
```

It uses XPATH for selecting html parts, but LINQ also could be used. There are a lot of [samples](https://www.google.de/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=12&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=HtlAgilityPack%20from#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=HtmlAgilityPack%20sample&oq=HtmlAgilityPack%20sample&aq=f&aqi=g1g-K1g-bK1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i30j0i8i30.340117.341113.0.341331.6.6.0.0.0.0.156.576.5j1.6.0...0.0.IKAR1XNZfrU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=79e49ec59cb9bd64&biw=1600&bih=756) how to use it